# List of bought applications in Ubuntu Software Center or login.ubuntu.com

Tags: software-center, package-management

I am trying to google out where can I find list of applications that I have bought in Ubuntu Software Center or login.ubuntu.com or some other place. is there a way to track them somehow?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

well the same idea was posted http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/29810/

Well as you can see in the link the idea was closed as rated as a bug. So it is a **bug**

il try to find the bug report.

Comment: ok there is a way: https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/ but it is not linked to any place in your account - and it should be :)